# How could we take projections of an ellipsoid on $x$, $y$ and $z$ axes?

Tags: geometry, projection

Given the quadratic form

```
f[x_,y_,z_]:=200.456+2.340*10^10*x^2+7.99*10^7*y^2+
  y*(2.80*10^(-9)-1.1735*10^6*z) -29150.591*z+1.895*10^6*z^2+
  x(-4.329*10^6-9.731*10^7*y+3.135*10^8*z);
```

I define the ellipsoid defined by $f(x,y,z)\leq 1$ as follows

```
RegionPlot3D[f[x, y, z] <= 1 ,
 {x, 0.00008, 0.000102}, {y, -0.0000555, 0.00017}, {z, -0.00099, 0.0012}, 
 AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, Mesh -> None, ImageSize -> Medium, 
 PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]

I would like to obtain the projection of the ellipsoid onto each one of the $Ox$, $Oy$ and $Oz$ axes.

Also, [can we do the projection in the wall of the x-y, y-z, and z-x plane so that the black point is also visible into the wall?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/244504/how-could-we-take-projections-of-an-ellipsoid-on-x-y-and-z-axes/244511#comment615556_244511)

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/199612/how-to-project-3d-image-in-the-planes-xy-xz-yz

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/189470/find-bounding-box-of-arbitrary-3d-graphics -- Also, possibly: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/92466/how-to-show-the-projections-of-3d-orbit-on-the-three-primary-planes

Answer (score 8):

Using [@kglr's projectToWalls](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/199613/4999):

```
(* https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/199613/4999 *)
ClearAll[projectToWalls]
projectToWalls = 
  Module[{pr = PlotRange[#]}, 
    Normal[#] /. 
     Line[x_, ___] :> {Line[x], 
       Line[x /. {a_, b_, c_} :> {pr[[1, 1]], b, c}], 
       Line[x /. {a_, b_, c_} :> {a, pr[[2, 2]], c}], 
       Line[x /. {a_, b_, c_} :> {a, b, pr[[3, 1]]}]}] &;

cp = ContourPlot3D[
  200.456 + 2.340*10^10*x^2 + 7.99*10^7*y^2 + 
    y*(2.80*10^(-9) - 1.1735*10^6*z) - 29150.591*z + 1.895*10^6*z^2 + 
    x*(-4.329*10^6 - 9.731*10^7*y + 3.135*10^8*z) == 1, {x, 0.00008, 
   0.00011}, {y, -0.00011, 0.00022}, {z, -0.0015, 0.0015}];

projectToWalls@cp
```

[image]

*Update:*

If range of `cp` on axes is actually desired (since an ellipsoid is path-connected):

```
PlotRange@Show[cp, PlotRangePadding -> 0, PlotRange -> All]
(*
{{ 0.0000820059, 0.0001018},
 {-0.0000560249, 0.000169893},
 {-0.000991714,  0.00119972}}
*)
```

This is a numerical approximation. For more accuracy, increase `PlotPoints` or `MaxRecursion`. With `MaxRecursion -> 4`, we get the following:

```
{{ 0.0000819949, 0.000101789},
 {-0.000055904,  0.000169853},
 {-0.000990615,  0.00119862}}
```

*Second update:*

For more control of what is projected (requested in a comment):

```
ClearAll[projectToWalls]
projectToWalls[g_Graphics3D, prim_ : Line] := 
  Module[{pr = PlotRange[g]},
   Normal[g] /. (p : prim)[x_, r___] :> {p[x, r],
      p[x /. {a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ} :>
         {pr[[1, 1]], b, c}],
      p[x /. {a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ} :>
         {a, pr[[2, 2]], c}],
      p[x /. {a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ} :>
         {a, b, pr[[3, 1]]}]}];
```

Example from comment:

```
cp = Show[
   ContourPlot3D[
    200.456 + 2.340*10^10*x^2 + 7.99*10^7*y^2 + 
      y*(2.80*10^(-9) - 1.1735*10^6*z) - 29150.591*z + 
      1.895*10^6*z^2 + 
      x*(-4.329*10^6 - 9.731*10^7*y + 3.135*10^8*z) == 1, {x, 0.00008,
      0.00011}, {y, -0.00011, 0.00022}, {z, -0.0015, 0.0015}, 
    ContourStyle -> Directive[{Orange, Opacity[0.5]}], Mesh -> None], 
   Graphics3D[{Black, PointSize[0.02], 
     Point[{9.19*10^(-5), 5.67*10^(-5), 10.78*10^(-5)}]}]];
projectToWalls[cp, Polygon | Point]
```

Notes: `Point` as well as geometric 3D shapes can be rendered in `Graphics3D` only as 3D shapes, not flat projections.  To get a 2D projection would require subroutines that discretize these objects to polygons that are projected flat against the bounding box.  Projecting polygons results in overlapping polygons that do not look good usually.

Comment: The question is about the projections on the coordinate axes, not the  coordinate planes. This is not it.

Comment: I wonder the upvotes for the incorrect answer.

Comment: Yes. @user64494, you are absolutely right.

Comment: Show[ContourPlot3D[
  200.456 + 2.340*10^10*x^2 + 7.99*10^7*y^2 + 
    y*(2.80*10^(-9) - 1.1735*10^6*z) - 29150.591*z + 1.895*10^6*z^2 + 
    x*(-4.329*10^6 - 9.731*10^7*y + 3.135*10^8*z) == 1, {x, 0.00008, 
   0.00011}, {y, -0.00011, 0.00022}, {z, -0.0015, 0.0015}, 
  ContourStyle -> Directive[{Orange, Opacity[0.5]}], Mesh -> None], 
 Graphics3D[{Black, PointSize[0.02], 
   Point[{9.19*10^(-5), 5.67*10^(-5), 10.78*10^(-5)}]}]]. Using this code can we do the projection in the wall of the x-y, y-z, and z-x plane so that the black point is also visible into the wall?

Comment: @Michael E2 please see it.

Comment: @user64494 please see it.

Comment: @SahabubJahedi Why not edit your original  post and add the detail of your require!!!

Comment: Like people have never misspoken. The question body is code-only, which does not inspire confidence that thoughtfulness underlies the post. Nonetheless, the OP first agrees with user64494 and now follows up for an extension to projecting on the walls. - This answer was intended to show the OP whether the proposed duplicate solves the problem adequately.

Comment: That  https://www.dropbox.com/s/bxak6w9lvg2yd2r/%D0%97%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA%20%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%202021-04-13%2009.58.09.png?dl=0 was the answer by@MichaelE2 before his edit. Compare with my answer. In such cases I submit a new answer.

Comment: For those who don't know how to use the site, you can find previous edits more easily than going to dropbox by clicking on the "edit...ago" link in the middle to the left of the name/"community wiki". But I think it's easy enough just to look at the current post, since I marked the update by posting it below "*Update*". The only change I made above that was changing `Out[]` to a variable `cp`, so I could reuse it in the update. Strange to be criticized by a commenter for responding to their criticism in an early comment -- it starts to resemble harassment.

Comment: @MichaelE2, I have tried a lot to edit the question but I don't know why always it is showing some error. I don't understand why.

Comment: @SahabubJahedi I don't know either, especially with no hint as to what the error is. I thought there was an automatic check that would reject questions that we all or mostly code. Since your original post went through, they must have gotten rid of it. There were some bugs in it.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in such a way. First, we define the set under consideraration as an`ImplicitRegion`, raionalizing it for convenience:

```
r = ImplicitRegion[Rationalize[
200.4 + 2.3*10^10 x^2 + 8*10^7 y^2 + 
y*(2.8*10^-9 - 1.17*10^6*z) - 29150.6*z + 1.9*10^6*z^2 + 
x*(-4.3*10^6 - 9.73*10^7*y + 3.13*10^8*z) == 1 && 
x >= 0.00008 && x <= 0.00011 && y >= -0.00011 && y <= 0.00022 && 
z >= -0.0015 && z <= 0.0015, 10^-35], {x, y, z}];
```

Second, we project `r` onto the $x$-axis by

```
rx = TransformedRegion[r, Function[p, {p[[1]], 0, 0 }]];
```

Finally,

```
FullSimplify[RegionMember[rx, {x, y, z}]]
```

> `y == 0 && z == 0 &&  3 \[Sqrt]190042183023602016355407785916095142401 +  3066319841000000000000000 x >= 287992553863649997529 &&  3066319841000000000000000 x <=  287992553863649997529 +  3 \[Sqrt]190042183023602016355407785916095142401`

Addition. As the OP noticed, the ranges of the variables are not needed here. A typo in the equation of the ellipsiod is corrected too.

```
r1 = ImplicitRegion[Rationalize[
200.456 + 2.340*10^10*x^2 + 7.99*10^7*y^2 + 
y*(2.80*10^(-9) - 1.1735*10^6*z) - 29150.591*z + 
1.895*10^6*z^2 + 
x*(-4.329*10^6 - 9.731*10^7*y + 3.135*10^8*z) == 1, 10^-35], {x,
y, z}];
rx1 = TransformedRegion[r, Function[p, {p[[1]], 0, 0 }]];
FullSimplify[RegionMember[rx1, {x, y, z}]]
```

> `65785848361558179853764884731429 +  25000000000000 x (-57941282080071571622229 +  315245111239400000000000000 x) <= 0 && y == 0 && z == 0`

```
Reduce[65785848361558179853764884731429 + 
25000000000000 x (-57941282080071571622229 + 
315245111239400000000000000 x) <= 0 && y == 0 && z == 0, {x, y, z}, Reals] // N
```

> `0.0000819931 <= x <= 0.000101804 && y == 0. && z == 0.`

Comment: Another approach consists in `Maximize[z, 
 Rationalize[
  200.4 + 2.3*10^10 x^2 + 8*10^7 y^2 + y*(2.8*10^-9 - 1.17*10^6*z) - 
     29150.6*z + 1.9*10^6*z^2 + 
     x*(-4.3*10^6 - 9.73*10^7*y + 3.13*10^8*z) == 1 && x >= 0.00008 &&
    x <= 0.00011 && y >= -0.00011 && y <= 0.00022 && z >= -0.0015 && 
   z <= 0.0015, 10^-35], {x, y, z}]//N` which performs `{0.0014372, {x -> 0.0000838291, y -> 0.0000614881, z -> 0.0014372}}`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have given the limits i.e. {x,0.00008,0.00011},{y,-0.00011,0.00022},{z,-0.0015,0.0015} just to draw the ellipsoid. My object is to  take the projections of this ellipsoid 200.456+2.340*10^10*x^2+7.99*10^7*y^2+y*(2.80*10^(-9)-1.1735*10^6*z) - 
  29150.591*z+1.895*10^6*z^2+x*(-4.329*10^6-9.731*10^7*y+3.135*10^8*z)==1 on x,y and z axes. How can I do it?

Comment: @SabatJahedi. You are right: the ranges of the variables are not in need. I added it to my answer.

Comment: `Maximize[z, 
  Rationalize[
   200.456 + 2.340*10^10*x^2 + 7.99*10^7*y^2 + 
     y*(2.80*10^(-9) - 1.1735*10^6*z) - 29150.591*z + 1.895*10^6*z^2 +
      x*(-4.329*10^6 - 9.731*10^7*y + 3.135*10^8*z) == 1, 10^-35], {x,
    y, z}] // N` performs `{0.00120867,{x->0.0000845289,y->0.0000603497,z->0.00120867}}`. Pay your attention to the corrected equation: `2.340` instead of `2.3` and so on.

Comment: Thank you so much. Could you please explain it mathematically? why this 10^{-35} has been taken? For precision??

Comment: The range of `z` is between `Minimize[z,    Rationalize[    200.456 + 2.340*10^10*x^2 + 7.99*10^7*y^2 +       y*(2.80*10^(-9) - 1.1735*10^6*z) - 29150.591*z + 1.895*10^6*z^2 +       x*(-4.329*10^6 - 9.731*10^7*y + 3.135*10^8*z) == 1, 10^-35], {x,     y, z}] // N` and `Maximize[z,    Rationalize[    200.456 + 2.340*10^10*x^2 + 7.99*10^7*y^2 +       y*(2.80*10^(-9) - 1.1735*10^6*z) - 29150.591*z + 1.895*10^6*z^2 +       x*(-4.329*10^6 - 9.731*10^7*y + 3.135*10^8*z) == 1, 10^-35], {x,     y, z}] // N`. Yes, `10^-35` is chosen for precision. For example `10^-15` brings several intervals.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122938/discussion-between-sahabub-jahedi-and-user64494).

Answer (score 2):

Just a different way to get the same answers using optimization. For some reason using exact (rational) coefficients allows Mathematica to use `Min/Maximize` instead of `NMin/NMaximize` and avoids an error for the $y$-coordinate.

```
r[x_] := Rationalize[x, 10^(-15)]
f[x_, y_, z_] := 
  r@200.45691061895533 + r@2.340594489462856*^10 x^2 + 
   r@7.997019728083995*^7 y^2 + 
   y (r@2.805368856610765*^-9 - r@1.1735999605619283*^6 z) - 
   r@29150.59199218005 z + r@1.8958172135566808*^6 z^2 + 
   x (-r@4.3293045864756685*^6 - r@9.73117535392215*^7 y + 
      r@3.135471494987312*^8 z);
xMin = First@Minimize[{x, f[x, y, z] <= 1}, {x, y, z}];
xMax = First@Maximize[{x, f[x, y, z] <= 1}, {x, y, z}];
yMin = First@Minimize[{y, f[x, y, z] <= 1}, {x, y, z}];
yMax = First@Maximize[{y, f[x, y, z] <= 1}, {x, y, z}];
zMin = First@Minimize[{z, f[x, y, z] <= 1}, {x, y, z}];
zMax = First@Maximize[{z, f[x, y, z] <= 1}, {x, y, z}];
TableForm[N@{{xMin, xMax}, {yMin, yMax}, {zMin, zMax}},
          TableHeadings -> {{"x", "y", "z"}, {"Min", "Max"}}]

RegionPlot3D[f[x, y, z] <= 1 ,
  {x, xMin, xMax}, {y, yMin, yMax}, {z, zMin, zMax},
  AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, Mesh -> None, ImageSize -> Medium, 
  PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Same idea as projection onto Cartesian planes](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/244501/26598):
(Thanks @user64494 for simplification!)

```
L[x_, y_, z_] = 200.456 + 2.340*10^10*x^2 + 7.99*10^7*y^2 + 
  y*(2.80*10^(-9) - 1.1735*10^6*z) - 29150.591*z + 1.895*10^6*z^2 + 
  x*(-4.329*10^6 - 9.731*10^7*y + 3.135*10^8*z) == 1;
```

project onto the $x$-axis:

```
fx[x_] = Reduce[Resolve[Exists[{y, z}, L[x, y, z]], Reals], x, Reals]
(*    0.0000819931 <= x <= 0.000101804    *)
```

project onto the $y$-axis:

```
fy[y_] = Reduce[Resolve[Exists[{x, z}, L[x, y, z]], Reals], y, Reals]
(*    -0.0000565762 <= y <= 0.000170076    *)
```

project onto the $z$-axis:

```
fz[z_] = Reduce[Resolve[Exists[{x, y}, L[x, y, z]], Reals], z, Reals]
(*    -0.000993936 <= z <= 0.00120867    *)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Could you please explain it mathematically? What are the values of x, y, and z?

Comment: The command `Reduce[-9.62227*10^-9 - 0.0001135 y + 1. y^2 <= 0, y, Reals]` results in `-0.0000565762<=y<=0.000170076` and a warning "Reduce::ratnz: Reduce was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result.".

Comment: Just to campare. `Minimize[y, 
  Rationalize[
   200.456 + 2.340*10^10*x^2 + 7.99*10^7*y^2 + 
     y*(2.80*10^(-9) - 1.1735*10^6*z) - 29150.591*z + 1.895*10^6*z^2 +
      x*(-4.329*10^6 - 9.731*10^7*y + 3.135*10^8*z) == 1, 10^-35], {x,
    y, z}] // N ` results in `{-0.0000565762, {x -> 0.0000918975, y -> -0.0000565762, 
  z -> 0.0000723856}}`.

Comment: @SahabubJahedi just look up the documentation on [`Exists`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Exists.html) and [`Resolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Resolve.html). The last [`Reduce`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html) is just for simplification.

Comment: @Roman, Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[
   200.456 + 2.340*10^10*x^2 + 7.99*10^7*y^2 + 
     y*(2.80*10^(-9) - 1.1735*10^6*z) - 29150.591*z + 1.895*10^6*z^2 +
      x*(-4.329*10^6 - 9.731*10^7*y + 3.135*10^8*z) == 
    1, {{x, 0.00008, 0.00011}, {y, -0.00011, 0.00022}, {z, -0.0015, 
     0.0015}}];
bd = RegionBounds[reg]
Graphics3D[{{Red, DiscretizeRegion[reg, Method -> "ContourPlot3D"]}, 
  Opacity[.5], 
  HighlightMesh[Cuboid @@ Transpose@bd, 
   Style[{1, {5, 2, 3}}, {Thickness[.02], Red}]]}, 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, Boxed -> False]
```

> `{{0.0000819931, 0.000101804}, {-0.0000565762,  0.000170076}, {-0.000993936, 0.00120867}}`

[image]

Comment: Clearly the best answer! What would you change to have a smooth ellipsoid in the graphic?

Comment: @A.G. Thanks! But I also don't how to do this, so we have to use `Show` the `Contourplot3D` instead of `DiscretizeREgion[reg]`